# Scroll over list in fixed content

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I would like to enable the scroll over a list of items while the content of the page is fixed.

Here it is my code:

```
<ion-content >
  <div style="width:94.5%; height:40%; margin:0 auto; margin-top:3%; margin-bottom:0%" #map="" id="map"></div>
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true">
      <ion-list class="list-style" no-border>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let location of locations">
          <ion-icon item-start name="star"></ion-icon>
          {{location.name}}
          <button ion-button icon-left outline item-end><ion-icon name="images"></ion-icon> Ver</button>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

And an image of the app:

[image]

I can scroll over the list of items, but i would like to fix the rest of the content. How can i achieve this?

Thanks so much

Comment: How about putting the rest in a separet div tag with position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can add position: fixed to the div that the map/other content is, and let the rest of the content scroll.

CSS:

```
.position-fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="position-fixed">Map goes here</div>
<div>Scrolling content goes here</div>
```